# What are the new features in bootstrap 3 in comparison to bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

just noticed the new version of bootstrap is available, rc 3.

can anyone provide a simple breakdown of the differences compared to the previous version  2.3.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this migration guide from v2 to v3](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide) pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

The [v3 Pull Request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342) on GitHub contains a discussion regarding all the changes in V3. Have a read of that.